# How to validate that UTF-8 columns actually save space?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2019 introduces support for the widely used UTF-8 character encoding.

I have a large table that stores sent emails. So I'd like to give this feature a try.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.EmailMessages 
ALTER COLUMN Body NVARCHAR(MAX) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8;

ALTER TABLE dbo.EmailMessages  REBUILD;
```

My concern is that I don't know how to verify size gains. It seems that popular scripts for size estimation do not properly report size in this case.

Comment: That's probably not the best way to save space.

Comment: hmm, does COLLATION really affects how data is *stored*. I'm pretty sure the nvarchar storage is still USC-2, or whatever microsoft call it these days

Comment: @siggemannen, yes, turns out column must have type VARCHAR otherwise there is no effect.

Comment: @mitch-wheat, what do you mean by that?

Comment: oh, so they implemented UTF8 by doing columns as varchar, very interesting! @kemsky, check out DATA_COMPRESSION=ROW as alternative to this. It made a lot of savings for our data

Comment: @siggemannen you're probably thinking of UCS-2 which only handles the Basic Multilingual Plane (Plane 0), and is different than UTF-16 which encodes the entire range of Unicode code points including all the fancy new emoji in the Supplementary Planes.

Comment: You can use [this db<>fiddle query](https://dbfiddle.uk/8BF_nHYJ) to compare lengths for various strings. For demo purposes, I just pulled a bunch of language names off of the language dropdown on the [Wikipedia UTF-8 page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). You can replace the source table with your own data and perhaps sum up the results. Bottom line, UTF-8 is almost always more efficient space-wise. Only for a handful of Asian character sets (Like Chinese or Korean) does UTF-8 take up more space.

Comment: Another [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/c9AjSpSO) that also include a hex dump of the encodings.

Comment: @t-n, thank you, it can be used to estimate gains before applying changes.

Comment: @TN, very nice fiddle, really informative. I wonder how many functions doing DATALENGTH stuff (cause LEN doesn't count spaces) will suddenly break by assuming VARCHAR is always DATALENGTH = Real length.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out DATALENGTH(). I posted my query as an answer and have modified it to use DATALENGTH, which eliminates the VARBINARY conversion (at least for the bytes calculation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, you should use `VARCHAR` instead of `NVARCHAR` to store UTF-8 encoded text.

You can use a query like the following to compare string lengths. It assumes a table named `@Data` with an `NVARCHAR` column called `String`.

```
SELECT *
FROM @Data
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), String COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8) AS Utf8String
) U
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        LEN(String) AS Length,
        --LEN(Utf8String) AS Utf8Length,
        DATALENGTH(String) AS NVarcharBytes,
        DATALENGTH(Utf8String) AS Utf8Bytes
) L
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN Utf8Bytes < NVarcharBytes THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END AS IsShorter,
        CASE WHEN Utf8Bytes > NVarcharBytes THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END AS IsLonger
) C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), String), 1) AS NVarcharHex,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Utf8String), 1) AS Utf8Hex
) H
```

You can replace `FROM @Data` with something like `FROM (SELECT Email AS String FROM YourTable) D` to query your specific data. Replace `SELECT *` with `SELECT SUM(NVarcharBytes) AS NVarcharBytes, SUM(Utf8Bytes) AS Utf8Bytes` to get totals.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UgWHaVwi).

See also: [Storage differences between UTF-8 and UTF-16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver16#storage_differences).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, column type must be converted to `VARCHAR(MAX)` then data is stored in a more compact manner:

> To limit the amount of changes required for the above scenarios, UTF-8
> is enabled in existing the data types CHAR and VARCHAR. String data is
> automatically encoded to UTF-8 when creating or changing an object’s
> collation to a collation with the “_UTF8” suffix, for example from
> LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC to LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8.

Size can be inspected using `sp_spaceused`:

```
sp_spaceused N'EmailMessages';
```

If unused space is high then you might need to `reorganize`:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.EmailMessages REORGANIZE WITH (LOB_COMPACTION = ON);
```

In my case size was reduced by a factor of ~2 (mostly English text).